# Component changes when input gets value Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

```
<component1 *ngIf="field != '' " //component 1 should load if value is Not empty
<component2 *ngIf="field == '' " //component 2 should load if value is empty
   <Mat-Select></Mat-select>
```

when the Select from component number 2 gets a value it changes to component number 1.Im not sure why this would happen because in component2 the value gets assigned to a different variable in another object.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing strict comparison operator?

`==`checks for reference equality

`===` for value.

I suspect that is your issue.

Comment: This answer makes sense, the OP can also improve their code IMO but doing truthy/falsey checks instead. `*ngIf="!field"`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, that didnt solve the problem however. Maybe this can clear it up. Component 1 has a defined variable for time so I load it if its not empty. Component 2 has an undefined variable for time via a select option for time. When the time is selected in component 2 it changes to component 1, which doesnt seem to make sense as the value is gets assigned to a different Object.